# Why Iterators.size() making the iterator empty?

Tags: java, iterator, guava

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "abcgdj");
    json.put("no", "1234");
    json.put("contact", "6748356");
    Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
    System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));
    System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));
}
```

In this code, after executing `Iterators.size(keys)`, the iterator is becoming empty and for the second print statement, it returning 0.

The `size()` method is under the package `com.google.common.collect.iterators`.So I've looked the code of Iterators.size() function.It was,

```
 public static int size(Iterator<?> iterator) {
    long count = 0L;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
    count++;
  }
  return Ints.saturatedCast(count);
}
```

So I have a doubt that how the iterator `keys` becomes empty. whether it is called by reference?

Can anyone explain what's happening inside size() function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));
```

[As it says in the Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#size-java.util.Iterator-), this exhausts the `keys` iterator: it just keeps calling `next()` until `hasNext()` is false.

Then it's not reset before you call

```
System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));
```

again (because there's no way to reset an iterator). So `hasNext()` immediately returns false, so there are no more elements for it to read. Hence the size is zero.

You'd need to reassign the variable with a new iterator:

```
Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();
System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));

keys = json.keys();  //

System.err.println(Iterators.size(keys));
```

or don't declare a variable (since it's effectively (*) useless afterwards):

```
System.err.println(Iterators.size(json.keys()));
System.err.println(Iterators.size(json.keys()));
```

(*) You could use it to remove the last element of the iterator.